# Power Query add-on fetching OData feed working using SSO not working

Tags: excel, odata, single-sign-on, powerquery, sap-gateway

I am trying to fetch data in Excel using OData feed. This was working perfectly fine with Basic Authentication.

Later on, SSO was implemented on server. Now every request is redirected to a site for SAML authentication.

OData -:

**`https://tsmag.*******.co.in/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_********_SRV_01/et_*******?$filter= ***** eq '*****'&$format=json`**

This is working perfectly fine in any browser. But not working in the Power Query Add-on (Excel 2013) neither through Windows Auuthentication nor through Basic Authentication

Error prompted is -:

> Blockquote OData: The given URL neither points to an OData service or a feed: 'https://rnr.*****.co.in/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=fZFdS8MwFIb/Ssl9P7duNqyFsjooqAwnXngjMTllgTSpOemc/960Q5kXevty3o8n2SDr1UDr0R31I7yPgC5om5IcxGrVAXQi5DcJD1MQ6/AtL0S4yJMcFnmxzHJGgmewKI0uSRYlJGgRR2g1Oqadl5J0HaZpmBVPSUGXGV2uX0jQ+AapmZtdR+cGpHFstY0ccwwdgIq4iaSOmegwVhiTYGcsh3lhSTqmEKamPUOUJ/hRakSwU+rWaBx7sAewJ8n9HAHnkvh1515ppDNvSUarqWEokWrWA1LH6aG+v6Oegw7WOMONItVmuqYzlr3y/29n30tItbvdv9bN7rCJr4IuqQN98M622Rsl+efE2DP3d3AapbMiRdjNp3TUOACXnQTh6ZUyH1sLzPkXcXYEEleX0t9/W30B&RelayState=oucdwwfeefdocyqcoredxobvzdotvqvetvzusva&SigAlg=http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256&Signature=Dw/1O0Y6B2VD+vQSpps9UyukG4LkLuH3EMMVWnbHVRzvkin1Jlu1UNyhalz7y1j3mc8G/lswOv6FFZ1ar/EJ5AZ+bGEjA0AcdWCzWROTdxCKEN6LqC4xhxMnokpQ1WEFFaOdLz5aZ/RIM0nZuCHIeI9EDjzV83l6qKgMYVoq/lE='."

The site rnr.*****.co.in is the site to which redirection is done for authentication.

Prior to SSO implementation, URL which was working using Basic Authentication was -: 
http://17*******:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_*****_SRV_01/et_******_reportSet?$filter= ****** eq '20171101'&$format=json

Comment: Are you still using Basic authentication? If your site has changed to SSO (using OAuth) then that won't work anymore since the authentication scheme is different. You need to use an Organizational account, although this may not work depending on which OAuth provider you use.

Comment: I tried using Windows authentication (Default credentials / Passing the ADID details). Gives the same error. Also, tried organizationanl account, but that is not recognizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by adding parameter ***`&saml2=disabled`*** in the OData URL.
This enabled the Basic Authentication (overriding the default Windows Authentication). 
Now the data is fetched by passing the Gateway / Fiori server username / password (Basic Authentication).

Updated URL -:

> https://****.*******.co.in/****/****/odata/****/Z_********_SRV_01/et_*******?$filter= ***** eq '*****'&$format=json&**saml2=disabled**

Comment: Thanks, this is correct - I was being challenged by AD's authentication. By adding the parameter I was able to employ basic authentication and use my SAP credentials. To vary the client I used the sap-client parameter in the URL

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found it was just that my initial URL entry was cached.
To clear that in 2016: Get Data -> Data Source Settings -> Global Permissions
You should see the URL there, and you can clear permissions.
Then when you try to connect to the URL again, you'll have the options to select the credentials you'd like to use.